# Invalid code for functioning link button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

This link when clicked opens a slideshow. The problem is, its not valid, even though it works perfectly. Is there a way to make this valid?

```
<input type="button" class="TryNow" value="Features Tour" href='tour_first.asp?' &Encode('platform=' &platType) &'' onclick='    return loadSlide(0);' />
```

Visual studio warns me at href, encode, platType and onclick.

The link is derived from the syntactically correct text link version, shown:

```
Response.Write("<a href=""tour_first.asp?" &Encode("platform=" &platType) &""" onclick=""return loadSlide(0);"">Tour</a>
```

Comment: Looks like you've got some mismatched quotes in your `href` attribute and `Encode` shouldn't start with an `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid because it has many syntax errors (you have to declare each attribute in one of these ways: `key='value'` or `key="value"`).

Moreover, [`input` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) has no `href`, `encode` and `playTipe` attributes. If you want to use custom attributes, you should read this article about [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Comment: Well that helped. Alot of what I passed in wasnt needed for the slider to show up. That being said though, I need to be able to set that platform type variable...

Answer (score 0):

On your `<input>` tag you need to include an href attribute pointing to the location you are trying to link to...